# how to detect div value (Django rendered) change with MutationObserver

Tags: html, django, render, mutation

I am rendering a value from django backend to frontend, and I am trying to detect the div value change with MutationObserver. Below is my current code:
MutationObserver part:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
          var element = document.getElementById('myTaskList');

          var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
          var observer = new MutationObserver(myFunction);
          observer.observe(element, {
            childList: true
          });

          function myFunction() {

            console.log("this is a trial")
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element.innerHTML);
          }

          // setTimeout(function(){
          //   element.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
          // }, 1000);
          //
          // setTimeout(function(){
          //   element.innerHTML = 'Hello Space!';
          // }, 2000);
        });
```

html part:

```
<div hidden id="myTaskList">{{resultList | safe}}</div>
```

I am rendering a string "dummyValue" to the  div, but just don't see the value from the console.log() statements inside function.

this works well when I uncomment the setTimeout functions though.

Thanks for any help on why MutationObserver won't detect the rendered div value

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the reason. Hope this might be helpful for people having similar issues in the future.

So, basically I was using my Django form submit button to do two actions at one time:
   1. submit data to the view and process the data in the view;
   2. trigger another function with the click action through 
      Ajax.

The second action was blocked by the first action, and I was only able to get result from action 1.

My solution: I modified action 1 to use Ajax as well. As I mentioned above, I originally used the Django form to submit data. I trigger action 2 inside the success function of action 1.  Everything is working well now.